# Query in Hibernate with HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql, jpql

I have been trying for a long time to make a simple query with HQL but it always return me

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: 
unexpected token: on near line 1, column 72 
[select p, g.Description from entity.TB_Person p inner join TB_Gender g 
 on p.IdGender = g.Id where p.Username= :Username]
```

Here is the code for the query:

```
String jpql = "select p, g.Description "
            + "from TB_Person p inner join TB_Gender g "
            + "on p.IdGender = g.Id where p.Username= :Username";
Query query = manager.createQuery(jpql);
query.setParameter("Username", credentials.getUsername());
List l = (List)query.getResultList();
```

Here are my entities:

```
package entity;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.ForeignKey;

@Entity
@Table(name="TB_Person")
public class TB_Person {

@Id
private String CPF;

private String Name;

private Date Birthday; 

private String PhotoPath;

@ForeignKey(name = "fk_TB_Person_TB_User1")
private String Username;

@ForeignKey(name = "fk_person_gender")
private int IdGender;
public String getUsername() {
    return Username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    Username = username;
}

public String getCPF() {
    return CPF;
}

public void setCPF(String cPF) {
    CPF = cPF;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

public Date getBirthday() {
    return Birthday;
}

public void setBirthday(Date birthday) {
    Birthday = birthday;
}

public String getPhotoPath() {
    return PhotoPath;
}

public void setPhotoPath(String photoPath) {
    PhotoPath = photoPath;
}
}

package entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="TB_Gender")
public class TB_Gender {

    @Id
    private int Id;

    private String Description;

    private String Abbreviation;

    public String getDescription() {
        return Description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        Description = description;
    }

    public String getAbbreviation() {
        return Abbreviation;
    }

    public void setAbbreviation(String abbreviation) {
        Abbreviation = abbreviation;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are not establishing the relationships between entities correctly.

`@ForeignKey` represents a [constraint](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/javadocs/org/hibernate/mapping/ForeignKey.html) but does not represent the relationship itself between java entities.

Until Hibernate 5.1 version, you can not use join between entities in JPQL if you do not have established previously a relation between them using annotations like `@OneToOne, @OneToMany, @ManyToOne`, ... More [info](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/how-to-join-unrelated-entities/) about this subject and how to join unrelated entities.

To execute your query, you have to define something like this in your entities

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name="TB_Person")
 public class TB_Person {

     @Id
     private String CPF;

     @OneToOne
     @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") // <- table column constrained by fk_TB_Person_TB_User1
     private TB_User user;

     ...
 }
```

Comment: Thank you RubioRic, i change @ForeignKey to  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") and set reference to entity not to property Id and solve the problem.